# QML unable to assign undefined to qstring

Tags: qml

I'm trying to append an image to `listview` dynamically. If I do it using `ListElement` and specifying the path statically , it works but if I try to do it using `FileDialog.fileUrl.toString()` in the `onAccepted` event, it throws the error I mentioned in the title. The file URL gets printed successfully on console though.
Here's the relevant code:

```
FileDialog {
    id: aImage
    title: "Please choose a file"
    folder: shortcuts.pictures
    nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png)", "All files (*)" ]
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + aImage.fileUrl.toString())
        listModel.append({username: "Akash", src: aImage.fileUrl.toString()});
        listView.positionViewAtEnd();
        }
}
```

Here is the Image element of the ListView's item delegate:

```
    Image{
    id: image
    height: 50
    width: 50
    source: src
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("src: " + src);
    }
```

Comment: Works fine (and there's nothing wrong with the posted code). Probably the relevant part is missing. Please, try to provide a full working example.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo thanks for replying. Can you please post the code you tested with? I've cross checked it and this is the most relevant code that anyone needs to see.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Strange enough, I did some suspicious changes. It worked. But now that I've commented those changes, it works as well as it should.

Comment: That's why I always push for complete working examples: it's a way to shrink the problem to a minimum, focus and, sometimes, find the solution yourself. :) Glad you solved. That was probably not related to the posted code.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo 
I only added `        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        z: 3` in the `Image{}` and then commented them. To my surprise it was still working fine. Still need to figure out why is it behaving this way..